# pip commands not able to install packages successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am unable to successfully install packages from pip commands in my jupyter notebook. Each time I use pip commands, it shows:

**Example:** pip install matplotlib

```
Requirement already satisfied: .....

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy(appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy(appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -umpy(appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
```

I tried different commands like sudo, !, python -m pip. But nothing works. I am constantly getting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

**pip version:** `pip 21.2.4 from C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`

Comment: Please use virtual environment for better library management

Answer (score 0):

Use the direct pip of your python using the command:

```
my/path/to/python -m pip install matplotlib
```

Often pip is linked with python 2.7 if you have it.
Then pip3 is linked with your first python3 installation.
You have to use directly `python -m pip` to be sure you are installing modules in the right python directory.

Comment: Not working, i am getting `python -m pip install matplotlib
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It seems you don t have pip on your python installation please run this script: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and retry